# Visual Studio - Setting a different port per solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have different solutions that I need to run one after another (not in parallel), but I usually need to swap from one to another quickly.
The issue is that I receive an error that states that the port is already in use, if I exit Visual Studio and re-open the solution, I can debug without issues.

I think the issue is that both the solutions try to use the same port 50847, so basically setting a specific port per solution should solve the problem ?

Any suggestion on this ?

Comment: What _"port"_? What type of project are you creating?  VS does not use a port to debug unless you have created a project that is using IIS Express (e.g. ASP.NET). The problem lies with IIS Express not VS.  In that case you might want to consider using IIS proper

Comment: Actually it is an ASP.NET project, and I think you're right about the fact that the problem is with IIS, but the issue is that for IIS it's only one site, that is built by using the 2 solutions... any idea on how can I proceed with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that socket is a TcpClient, you can switch `ExclusiveAddressUse` to `false` and set the linger option to false / 0. In case of server, SocketListener has that ExclusiveAddressUse as well. That way your solutions should no longer block eachother.

```
socket = new TcpClient();
socket.LingerState = new LingerOption(false, 0);
socket.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
socket.NoDelay = true;
```

Comment: I would have thought the TCP port like any other Windows handle to be closed when the process is terminated?